# How to use Soundcloud in tor-browser? it need flash-player!

Tags: flash, tor-browser

I am in Iran and have to use tor-browser in my Ubuntu 14.04.
But it has a problem with flash-player in "Soundcloud". I installed many flash-player add-ons on it. but it not helped me and site say to me that need flash-player to play musics. thanks.

Comment: This is a bad idea. The point of Tor Browser is to make your browser indistinguishable from others. If you use another browser than Tor browser your are not anonymous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to use flash with tor. It ruins the whole point of using tor. However, if you still want to use it I'll suggest chrome with this command:

```
chromium-browser --proxy-server="socks://127.0.0.1:9050" --incognito check.torproject.org
```

If doesn't work do:

```
killall chromium-browser
```

Then try again

You must run tor first by

```
tor&
```

I assumed that tor and chromium-browser is installed on your system. If not install them from software center. However, I forgot to mention one thing. You need to find out at which port tor is listening to. To do that, simply run this command:

```
tor
```

without the "&" sign. It will give a output in terminal. Look for this in the output:

[notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050

Those digits might be different on your system. Put that thing in the previous chromium-browser command.

Answer (score 0):

Flash-Player is very insecure and very dangerous technology. Malicious executable code (like viruses and spyware) can be hidden inside it. That's why Google is planning of deactivating it by default in future Chrome/Chromium versions.
I love SoundCloud too, but i have Flash-Player more, that's why i stopped using Soundcloud. At least until they replace Flash with something else.

Allowing Flash to run on your PC is equivalent to letting spyware into your computer, and that defeats the whole purpose of Tor. Your anonymity WILL be compromised! Your privacy TOO!